# Horizontally align inference rules

Tags: horizontal-alignment

I'm using the `bussproofs` package to write some inference rules, but i'd like to horizontally align them. I tried to write them within a two-columned table (one rule in the left cell and the other in the right), but it doesn't work. Any suggestions, please?

Code producing the error, below:

```
\begin{tabular}{cc}
{\begin{prooftree}
\AxiomC{$\Gamma, A \vdash B$}
\RightLabel{\scriptsize{\emph{$\Rightarrow_\mathcal{I}$}}}
\UnaryInfC{$\Gamma \vdash A\Rightarrow B$}
\end{prooftree}} & {} \\
\end{tabular}
```

The second inference rule is missing from the code.

Comment: It would be great if you could provide a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://goo.gl/dtPzv) that replicates your "doesn't work" instance.

Comment: I'm using Gummi. It doesn't produce the pdf and the Build Log tab is just blank. So i don't know which is the error. But If it is of any help, I will add the code producing the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the end, I used the `mathpartir` package and I made it.

```
\begin{mathpar}
\inferrule*[Right=\selectlanguage{english}\emph{Id}\selectlanguage{greek}]{{}}{\Gamma, A \dashv A}
\and 
\inferrule*[Right=$\bot_\mathcal{E}$]{\Gamma \vdash \bot}{\Gamma \vdash A}
\end{mathpar}
```

Comment: It would be helpful for anyone else wondering about this, or a similar problem, if you explained just how you solved it, perhaps including a minimal code example.

Comment: ok, just did :)